# Heroku, S3, Paperclip one model uploads fine, the other doesn't no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

Alright so I have 2 models with uploads, an Auction and a User.

I'm using Paperclip, Rails 3.2, and Ruby 1.9.3. The platform is Heroku Cedar.

Here's the credential details:

```
S3_BUCKET = ENV['S3_BUCKET'] || "..."
S3_ID = ENV['S3_ID'] || "AKIAJXD4ZBGYF24..."
S3_KEY = ENV['S3_KEY'] || "fJ7eNKQtFGf1s..."
S3_UPLOAD_OPTIONS = {
  storage: :s3,
  bucket: S3_BUCKET,
  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id: S3_ID,
    secret_access_key: S3_KEY
  }
}
```

Auction file uploads are working fine. Everything is as expected.

User uploads do not work, and have zero errors as shown below:

```
2012-05-17T20:39:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-17T20:39:16+00:00 app[web.1]: DalliError: No server available
2012-05-17T20:39:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-17T20:39:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-17T20:39:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/users" for 208.117.193.99 at 2012-05-17 20:39:16 +0000
2012-05-17T20:39:18+00:00 heroku[router]: POST cfac-staging.herokuapp.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2006ms status=302 bytes=113
2012-05-17T20:39:18+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /users] invalidate, pass
2012-05-17T20:39:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-17T20:39:18+00:00 app[web.1]: DalliError: No server available
2012-05-17T20:39:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-17T20:39:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-17T20:39:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auctions/new" for 208.117.193.99 at 2012-05-17 20:39:18 +0000
2012-05-17T20:39:19+00:00 heroku[router]: GET cfac-staging.herokuapp.com/auctions/new dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1154ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-05-17T20:39:19+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /auctions/new] miss
2012-05-17T20:39:19+00:00 app[web.1]: DalliError: No server available
2012-05-17T20:39:19+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/blank-avatar-9a23306b75ac790741fc7e05300183b6.png] miss
2012-05-17T20:39:19+00:00 heroku[router]: GET cfac-staging.herokuapp.com/assets/blank-avatar-9a23306b75ac790741fc7e05300183b6.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2212
2012-05-17T20:39:19+00:00 app[web.1]: DalliError: No server available
2012-05-17T20:39:19+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/get-started-button-f7e9baac88feb2effa461b697df8bcd9.png] miss
2012-05-17T20:39:19+00:00 heroku[router]: GET cfac-staging.herokuapp.com/assets/get-started-button-f7e9baac88feb2effa461b697df8bcd9.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2451
```

I have no idea why the DalliError bit is happening either, so...

Here are the User and Auction models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :logo, { styles: { medium: "x125", thumb: "x40" } }.merge!(S3_UPLOAD_OPTIONS)
end

class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image,  { styles: { medium: "122x122#", thumb: "80x80#" }, default_url: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('blank-avatar.png') }.merge!(S3_UPLOAD_OPTIONS)
end
```